# How to disable & Enable input element with html selector option

Tags: javascript, css

I want to make input element `name="sellprice"` enable if i select value `sell` option else input element will be disabled.

```
<select id="selling" name="selling">
  <option value="">-- Choose --</option>
  <option value="free">Open Source</option>
  <option value="sell">I Wan't To Sell</option>
</select>

<div class="kd-title-show md-radio-inline">
  <label for="4">Price :</label>
  <input id="4" type="textbox" class="form-title" name="sellprice" placeholder="Min-$5 to Max-$100 " disabled>
</div>
```

Here is my Javascript Code, I have try this below code but it's not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select[name='selling']").on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val()== "free"){
      $("input[name='sellprice']").prop("disabled",false);
    }else{
      $("input[name='sellprice']").prop("disabled",true);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You appear to have mistaken stackoverflow for a code writing service. Please provide the code you've already tried and are struggling to get working in a [mcve]... otherwise you're just asking us to do work for you. Please have a read of the [help] and the [ask] section in particular

Comment: So what is stopping you from doing what you want? What have you researched? What have you tried? You need to handle the "change" event of the `select` element, get the selected value, and use it to decide whether to enable or disable the `input`. You can very easily research how to do each of those steps, they are all basic things in JavaScript.

Comment: i have change my question, i have try this code but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make input element name="sellprice" enable 
>   - that is not an input, it's a dropdown
>
> If i select value sell option else input element will be disabled. - from your current explanation i understand that you want to disable the drop-down if the third option is selected

If the third option is selected, the drop-down will be disabled.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mounth').change(function() { 
   if( $(this).val() == "sell") {
            $('#mounth').prop( "disabled", true );
        }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mounth" name="selling">
  <option value="">-- Choose --</option>
  <option value="free">Open Source</option>
  <option value="sell">I Don't Want To Sell</option> 
</select>

<div class="kd-title-show md-radio-inline">
  <label>Price :</label>
  <input id="textInput" type="textbox" class="form-title" name="sellprice" placeholder="Min-$5 to Max-$100 " disabled>
</div>
```

If you want to disable the input if the third option is selected, the following code will do it

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mounth').change(function() { 
   if( $(this).val() == "sell") {
         $('#textInput').prop( "disabled", true );
    } else {       
      $('#textInput').prop( "disabled", false );
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mounth" name="selling">
  <option value="" selected="selected">-- Choose --</option>
  <option value="free">Open Source</option>
  <option value="sell">I Don't want To Sell</option> 
</select>

<div class="kd-title-show md-radio-inline">
  <label>Price :</label>
  <input id="textInput" type="textbox" class="form-title" name="sellprice" placeholder="Min-$5 to Max-$100 ">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look I hope it's useful for you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select[name='selling']").on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val()== "sell"){
      $("input[name='sellprice']").prop("disabled",false);
    }else{
      $("input[name='sellprice']").prop("disabled",true);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<select id="mounth" onchange="myOnChangeFunction()" name="selling">
             <option value="">-- Choose --</option>
             <option value="free">Open Source</option>
             <option value="sell">I Wan't To Sell</option> 
         </select>

<div class="kd-title-show md-radio-inline">
  <label for="4">Price :</label>
  <input id="4" type="textbox" class="form-title" name="sellprice" placeholder="Min-$5 to Max-$100 " disabled>
</div>
```

in js

```
<script>
function myOnChangeFunction() {
  var val = document.getElementById("mounth").value;

if(val === "sell"){
document.getElementById('4').disabled = false;
}else{
document.getElementById('4').disabled = true;
}

}
</script>
```

Comment: i have change my question, please check.